# How could I find a LaTeX hourglass?

Tags: symbols

I look for a nice `LaTeX hourglass` unicode (U+231B) ⌛.

G**gle gives some nice things but nothing typeseting compatible.

Comment: I saw an uggly \hourglass that is made of two triangles.

Comment: I saw nothing in the comprehensive symbol list. The package `iftym` has some clock-related symbols. Could'nt that fit?

Comment: @Clément: You mean `ifsym`? Well, that contains a lot of clock symbols, but no hourglass. But also a lot of symbols I never thought I would use them ;-)

Comment: I'd go with a vectorized image and `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : Yes, `ifsym`, sorry.

Comment: @egreg : I'd search it on [openclipart](https://openclipart.org/search/?query=hourglass), but I think Tarass should makes his choice.

Comment: You could just use `}{`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for suitable fonts (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/231b/fontsupport.htm) and then use lualatex or xelatex to create a small pdf:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

{\LARGE\fontspec{Cambria}^^^^231b}
{\LARGE\fontspec{Arial Unicode MS}^^^^231b}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can directly [click here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%8C%9B%20-%20HOURGLASS%20%28U%2B231B%29) and see, if you have some fonts on your system that provide that symbol. If you are lucky (like me with Mathcad), you can use it as Ulrike said. Just in order to show the Mathcad symbol:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MathcadUniMath.otf}
\begin{document}
\symbol{"231B}
\end{document}
```

[image]